# Apple Silicon + CRA

Tags: reactjs, macos, create-react-app, apple-silicon

I have Mac Apple Silicon. I try to start the CRA app, but it's crashing. But my old projects work successfully. I don't do anything that can crash my system preferences or something else.

Comment: Log: https://pastebin.com/zP4QLiPp

Answer (score 0):

Try using nvm to install LTS version (see https://nodejs.org for more details) and use it to run the CRA:

- Install [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#installing-and-updating)
- restart terminal
- `nvm install --lts`
- `npm start